# Algorithm to recognise graphs from their values

Tags: computer-science, pattern-recognition

I don't know if it is a Math question or a Computer programming question. For sure a mathematician can help me solving this.

Crossposted in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673853/algorithm-to-recognise-graphs-from-their-values

If this is a wrong site to make these kind of questions please let me know, and I'll move it to another destination.

> **THE SCENARIO**

I am receiving data (at 100 Hz) from an IoT device from three different channels.

The graphs for these 3 different channels appear like the pictures you can see at the end of this requests, but this is just an example.

The data I receive from this channels are only numbers that identify the X and Y of every peak:

- X = WL = WaveLength
- Y = Power

> **THE REQUEST**

I need a way to understand only from the list of values received, from which channel I am receiving data.

> **Current algorithm** That I'd like to change.

- I sum all the powers of the channel at each cycle and compare it with the sum in the previous reading

  - Pro: fast
  - Cons: It is a bit weak if a peak disappear or a fake reading appear, In same cases the sum for all powers may be almost the same in two channels
- If the difference between two consecutive readings goes over a threshold I assume the channel is changed

[image: Difference of the sum of powers]

So for example the first graph is the difference of the sum of powers in two consecutive readings. It works fine but I can only know that the channel is changed, not which is the channel. And it is a bit weak if sensors disappear or worst if fake signals appear in the numbers. It believes the channel has changed but it did not.

In the second graph I was trying to introduce the WL in the formula:

WL1/(4001-Power1) + WL2/(4001-Power2) + ... with no success.

> **Things I tried so far**

- Check the number sensors (list of WL + powers) I receive from the channel to discriminate the channel itself

  - Example: C1 = 18 sensors, C3 = 15, C4 = 20
  - Cons: I cannot always count on this because of C:01 and C:02
- Use one of the sensors as a identifier for the entire channel

  - Example: only the channel 1 has the WL 1588
  - Cons: It may be possible that all three channels have the same number of sensors and similar WaveLengths + I cannot be sure because of C:01 or C:02

> **Constraints**

- C:01 - Sometimes one of the sensors it goes below a threshold (red line) and disappear

  - Sensors with low power (close to the threshold) are the most likely to disappear
- C:02 - Sometimes a fake sensor reading is returned (an extra couple of numbers: Power + WL)

  - A fake sensor may also appear with high power
- C:03 - When the channel transition from a channel to another, some readings do not have to be read
- C:04 - WL and powers do change a bit in each reading (Example: WL = 1526.5 +- 0.1nm, Power = 2000 +- 10 a.u.)

> **Notes**

- Looking at the pictures if is so easy to visually recognise a channel respect to the others, even if you remove one or two sensors or if you add one or two sensors :-(

> **DATA**

```
WL          Power
1524.8679   3999    1527.7981   345     1531.0068   3134    1533.938    3415    1537.0908   3756    1539.9895   3997    1546.1912   3996    1548.9048   946     1551.9819   1100    1555.0181   1280    1557.9159   1964    1561.2456   2861    1563.8372   3195    1566.7693   740 1569.8391       768     1572.6978   804     1575.8076   3997    1578.7158   3996    1581.7244   3995    1587.6741   3996        
1524.8682   3999    1527.7988   345     1531.0068   3140    1533.9385   3416    1537.0914   3748    1539.99     3997    1546.1917   4000    1548.9062   945     1551.9816   1097    1555.0188   1278    1557.9158   1961    1561.2463   2866    1563.8367   3207    1566.7703   744 1569.8398       785     1572.6995   806     1575.8068   3995    1578.7164   4000    1581.7245   3999    1587.6736   3997        
1524.8669   4000    1527.7991   346     1531.0068   3132    1533.9382   3414    1537.0918   3756    1539.9893   3995    1546.1919   3998    1548.9056   947     1551.9822   1100    1555.0186   1281    1557.9158   1958    1561.2458   2854    1563.8357   3193    1566.7683   740     1569.8394   786     1572.699    804     1575.8088   3994    1578.7178   4000    1581.7245   3999    1587.6731   3993        
1524.8678   3998    1527.7988   343     1531.0074   3143    1533.9382   3417    1537.0918   3750    1539.9897   3999    1546.1912   4000    1548.9067   945     1551.9817   1098    1555.019    1282    1557.9155   1964    1561.2458   2865    1563.8362   3191    1566.7686   740     1569.8396   782     1572.6992   806     1575.8062   3999    1578.7166   3996    1581.7244   3999    1587.672    3997        
1524.8677   3997    1527.7979   345     1531.0068   3140    1533.9382   3414    1537.0908   3742    1539.9895   3997    1546.192    4002    1548.9081   944     1551.9814   1095    1555.0184   1282    1557.9156   1962    1561.2467   2863    1563.8359   3173    1566.7698   745     1569.838    774     1572.6978   803     1575.8064   3998    1578.7185   3999    1581.7249   4000    1587.6724   3997        
1524.8667   3995    1527.7986   344     1531.0063   3136    1533.9392   3412    1537.0918   3750    1539.9893   4000    1546.1914   3997    1548.907    944     1551.9817   1097    1555.0183   1282    1557.9163   1962    1561.2466   2861    1563.8357   3195    1566.7687   739     1569.8383   783     1572.6978   804     1575.8074   4000    1578.7168   3994    1581.7256   4000    1587.6731   3997        
1524.8679   3999    1527.7983   345     1531.0062   3133    1533.9387   3418    1537.0911   3759    1539.9883   4000    1546.191    3996    1548.9058   944     1551.9811   1100    1555.0181   1281    1557.9165   1961    1561.246    2856    1563.8357   3193    1566.7683   737     1569.8394   782     1572.6973   806     1575.8064   4000    1578.7173   3995    1581.7256   3999    1587.6738   3997        
1524.868    3995    1527.7983   343     1531.0065   3140    1533.9392   3419    1537.0902   3747    1539.9897   3999    1546.1913   3998    1548.9066   945     1551.9818   1098    1555.0189   1277    1557.9141   1970    1561.2468   2875    1563.8369   3199    1566.7687   739     1569.8398   785     1572.6973   802     1575.8054   3999    1578.7156   3995    1581.7251   3999    1587.6731   3997        
1524.8685   4000    1527.7997   344     1531.0065   3135    1533.9388   3417    1537.0903   3748    1539.9895   3996    1546.1919   4000    1548.9075   946     1551.9818   1096    1555.0201   1281    1557.9148   1965    1561.2462   2868    1563.8362   3191    1566.7678   740     1569.8389   773     1572.6992   805     1575.8076   3995    1578.7168   4000    1581.7251   3999    1587.6721   3996        
1524.8688   4000    1527.7988   344     1531.0063   3142    1533.9382   3415    1537.0903   3751    1539.9906   3994    1546.1915   4000    1548.906    945     1551.9814   1098    1555.0198   1281    1557.9148   1963    1561.2454   2860    1563.8345   3196    1566.7704   745     1569.8394   776     1572.6968   806     1575.8074   3997    1578.7168   3999    1581.7244   4000    1587.6721   3997        
1524.8696   4000    1527.7981   347     1531.0067   3139    1533.9387   3417    1537.0916   3752    1539.9893   3995    1546.1913   4000    1548.9067   946     1551.9812   1097    1555.0193   1285    1557.915    1960    1561.2466   2870    1563.8364   3210    1566.7698   744     1569.8398   782     1572.696    801     1575.8079   3993    1578.7156   3999    1581.7241   3994    1587.672    3991        
1509.8767   629     1512.7954   522     1515.642    3999    1518.927    3993    1521.842    932     1524.8359   3995    1536.897    3989    1563.9879   1137    1566.8522   3997    1569.913    4009    1572.7224   540     1575.7368   673     1578.7592   3998    1581.6887   3997    1584.8557   3997                                                
1509.8772   629     1512.7957   521     1515.6416   3997    1518.9266   3997    1521.8416   931     1524.8357   3995    1536.8962   3993    1563.9885   1136    1566.8513   4000    1569.9126   4012    1572.7223   543     1575.7393   679     1578.7594   3998    1581.6904   3999    1584.8552   3996                                                
1509.8793   629     1512.7961   520     1515.6409   3999    1518.9265   3990    1521.8408   933     1524.8353   4000    1536.8955   3994    1563.9875   1136    1566.8511   3994    1569.9133   4004    1572.7249   541     1575.7393   673     1578.7595   3997    1581.6893   3996    1584.855    3998                                                
1509.8768   629     1512.7969   520     1515.6411   4000    1518.9259   3990    1521.8412   933     1524.8359   3999    1536.8958   3991    1563.9873   1137    1566.8519   3997    1569.913    4007    1572.7239   545     1575.738    673     1578.7589   3999    1581.6892   4000    1584.8545   3999                                                
1509.876    630     1512.7959   518     1515.6401   3998    1518.9275   3996    1521.8408   933     1524.8367   3999    1536.8955   3996    1563.9871   1137    1566.8506   3995    1569.9127   4012    1572.7236   543     1575.7361   673     1578.759    3995    1581.6902   3999    1584.855    3996                                                
1509.8763   631     1512.7969   519     1515.6409   3996    1518.9291   3994    1521.8405   931     1524.8357   4000    1536.8967   3995    1563.9878   1134    1566.8503   3997    1569.9131   4006    1572.7244   542     1575.7368   672     1578.7592   4000    1581.6897   3994    1584.854    3999                                                
1509.8766   627     1512.7972   518     1515.6406   3999    1518.9279   3989    1521.8411   929     1524.8356   4000    1536.8972   3993    1563.9878   1132    1566.8506   3998    1569.9143   4006    1572.7231   542     1575.7356   670     1578.7598   4000    1581.6885   3995    1584.855    4000                                                
1509.8762   628     1512.7966   518     1515.6404   3996    1518.9276   3993    1521.8408   930     1524.8358   4000    1536.8969   3992    1563.988    1132    1566.8508   3993    1569.9136   4007    1572.7227   540     1575.738    673     1578.7605   3999    1581.6897   3998    1584.8535   3999                                                
1509.8766   630     1512.7968   515     1515.6404   3998    1518.9277   3991    1521.8424   930     1524.8364   4002    1536.8965   3994    1563.9882   1139    1566.8508   3993    1569.9141   4004    1572.7244   542     1575.739    676     1578.7603   3998    1581.6899   3994    1584.8531   4000                                                
1509.8762   628     1512.7966   518     1515.6406   3999    1518.9266   3991    1521.8416   929     1524.8352   4000    1536.8965   3993    1563.9883   1140    1566.8513   3995    1569.9138   4009    1572.7231   539     1575.7383   676     1578.7598   4000    1581.6897   3995    1584.8539   3999                                                
1509.6763   3999    1512.7833   3989    1515.7435   3997    1518.856    3998    1521.8718   1695    1524.9299   1505    1527.8435   2907    1531.1213   2773    1533.9573   3996    1537.1021   3999    1539.9788   1477    1542.9346   522     1545.7588   1232    1548.9478   1491    1552.1178   812     1554.9543   1004    1557.8019   587     1560.8467   696                     
1509.6766   4000    1512.7839   3988    1515.7448   3997    1518.8561   3998    1521.8708   1696    1524.9299   1505    1527.844    2910    1531.121    2771    1533.9575   3998    1537.1025   3998    1539.9788   1476    1542.9333   522     1545.7589   1233    1548.9475   1494    1552.1169   814     1554.955    1004    1557.8008   586     1560.847    699                     
1509.6765   3998    1512.7832   3989    1515.7451   3999    1518.8567   3995    1521.8704   1692    1524.9302   1503    1527.8435   2906    1531.1208   2770    1533.9578   3997    1537.1007   4000    1539.9778   1475    1542.9342   523     1545.7592   1230    1548.9482   1495    1552.1169   811     1554.9546   1002    1557.8008   587     1560.8464   698                     
1509.6755   3994    1512.7831   3993    1515.7446   4000    1518.8574   3999    1521.8712   1694    1524.9282   1503    1527.8442   2908    1531.121    2770    1533.9573   3991    1537.1013   4000    1539.9786   1476    1542.9358   525     1545.7588   1224    1548.9486   1492    1552.1167   814     1554.9548   1002    1557.801    587     1560.8462   699                     
1509.6766   4000    1512.7836   3987    1515.7439   3996    1518.8567   3999    1521.8711   1696    1524.9291   1502    1527.8441   2907    1531.1213   2775    1533.9573   3999    1537.1006   3996    1539.9788   1471    1542.9355   522     1545.7583   1228    1548.949    1490    1552.1168   816     1554.9543   1004    1557.8015   584     1560.8448   703                     
1509.6763   4000    1512.7833   3988    1515.7439   3995    1518.8562   4000    1521.8702   1692    1524.9282   1505    1527.8441   2906    1531.1208   2775    1533.957    4000    1537.1008   3995    1539.9797   1473    1542.9353   522     1545.7603   1224    1548.9495   1488    1552.116    818     1554.9528   1004    1557.8026   591     1560.8442   695                     
1509.677    3995    1512.7816   3993    1515.7441   4000    1518.8564   3994    1521.8718   1693    1524.928    1500    1527.8445   2901    1531.1213   2782    1533.9575   3996    1537.1013   4000    1539.9773   1473    1542.9355   520     1545.76     1234    1548.9489   1489    1552.1147   812     1554.9547   1003    1557.8025   584     1560.845    698                     
1509.676    4000    1512.7825   3985    1515.7437   3994    1518.8563   4000    1521.8721   1693    1524.9282   1502    1527.8438   2912    1531.1208   2771    1533.958    4000    1537.1008   3996    1539.9778   1468    1542.9355   521     1545.7603   1235    1548.9475   1493    1552.1165   812     1554.9541   1003    1557.8013   584     1560.845    695                     
1509.6755   3999    1512.7834   3986    1515.7437   3997    1518.8574   3999    1521.8708   1694    1524.9285   1500    1527.8438   2911    1531.1201   2768    1533.9583   3999    1537.1014   3997    1539.9794   1478    1542.9343   520     1545.7598   1232    1548.9468   1490    1552.1169   813     1554.9548   1006    1557.8018   587     1560.8461   699                     
1509.6758   3997    1512.7832   3988    1515.7437   3996    1518.8567   4000    1521.8706   1693    1524.9296   1507    1527.8433   2905    1531.1208   2766    1533.9583   3996    1537.1025   3994    1539.978    1476    1542.9348   521     1545.76     1234    1548.947    1488    1552.1154   815     1554.9561   1005    1557.8008   587     1560.8462   696                     
1509.6761   3998    1512.7822   3991    1515.7439   4000    1518.8568   3995    1521.8701   1692    1524.9291   1501    1527.8435   2904    1531.1212   2780    1533.9578   3993    1537.103    4000    1539.979    1474    1542.9349   528     1545.7583   1230    1548.9479   1488    1552.115    813     1554.9543   1003    1557.8026   585     1560.8469   701                     
1524.8668   3997    1527.7976   343     1531.0068   3137    1533.9382   3418    1537.0916   3759    1539.9893   4000    1546.192    3999    1548.9065   943     1551.9817   1098    1555.0186   1282    1557.9148   1961    1561.2454   2859    1563.8356   3202    1566.7673   736     1569.8384   771     1572.7002   807     1575.8059   3996    1578.7166   3996    1581.7252   3997    1587.6722   3995        
1524.8666   4000    1527.7971   345     1531.0068   3132    1533.9384   3416    1537.0913   3746    1539.9901   3995    1546.1914   4000    1548.9062   945     1551.9812   1095    1555.0189   1280    1557.9148   1969    1561.2456   2862    1563.8348   3189    1566.7681   746     1569.8396   787     1572.699    803     1575.8057   3999    1578.7153   3996    1581.7246   4000    1587.6727   3998        
1524.8665   3995    1527.7993   345     1531.007    3132    1533.9385   3415    1537.0911   3755    1539.9907   4000    1546.1914   3996    1548.9067   944     1551.9813   1102    1555.0193   1283    1557.915    1967    1561.2451   2860    1563.8354   3204    1566.7668   740     1569.8425   786     1572.6985   804     1575.8066   3996    1578.7153   3999    1581.7241   3994    1587.6721   3993        
1524.8665   4000    1527.7993   346     1531.0073   3139    1533.9391   3424    1537.0911   3757    1539.9895   3994    1546.1917   3998    1548.9071   944     1551.9814   1096    1555.019    1282    1557.9148   1962    1561.2477   2858    1563.8357   3182    1566.7678   740     1569.84     782     1572.6985   807     1575.8071   3994    1578.7158   4000    1581.7246   3999    1587.6721   3996        
1524.8672   4000    1527.7997   345     1531.0074   3138    1533.939    3412    1537.0903   3756    1539.9902   3996    1546.1919   3996    1548.9067   948     1551.9812   1097    1555.0197   1281    1557.9146   1961    1561.2458   2857    1563.8362   3186    1566.7679   739     1569.8395   767     1572.696    800     1575.8057   3999    1578.715    3998    1581.7253   4000    1587.6731   4000        
1524.8669   3997    1527.7994   344     1531.0076   3140    1533.9382   3421    1537.09     3745    1539.9905   4000    1546.191    3998    1548.9066   943     1551.9817   1098    1555.0199   1279    1557.9143   1967    1561.2458   2858    1563.8359   3191    1566.769    743     1569.8386   783     1572.696    800     1575.8055   3997    1578.7161   3996    1581.7249   3996    1587.6733   3994        
1524.8672   4000    1527.7999   346     1531.0067   3140    1533.938    3413    1537.0903   3758    1539.9895   3995    1546.191    3999    1548.9072   947     1551.981    1100    1555.0193   1280    1557.9137   1959    1561.2458   2854    1563.8354   3199    1566.7683   740     1569.8398   782     1572.6965   804     1575.8059   4000    1578.7157   3999    1581.724    4000    1587.6738   3994        
1524.8663   4000    1527.7988   347     1531.0074   3140    1533.9375   3421    1537.0908   3757    1539.9893   3996    1546.1918   4002    1548.9077   948     1551.9816   1100    1555.0195   1280    1557.9146   1962    1561.2454   2856    1563.8351   3175    1566.769    743     1569.8409   786     1572.6985   808     1575.8074   4000    1578.7144   3997    1581.7238   4000    1587.6731   3998        
1524.8667   3998    1527.7993   345     1531.0076   3136    1533.938    3418    1537.0911   3748    1539.9893   3999    1546.1919   3996    1548.908    945     1551.9813   1099    1555.0194   1279    1557.9158   1963    1561.2466   2860    1563.8359   3191    1566.769    743     1569.8411   783     1572.6985   803     1575.8054   3994    1578.7136   4000    1581.7242   3998    1587.6726   3993        
1524.8673   4000    1527.7991   344     1531.0068   3137    1533.9387   3410    1537.0916   3751    1539.9897   3994    1546.1924   4000    1548.908    946     1551.9824   1099    1555.0195   1279    1557.9153   1959    1561.2458   2858    1563.8354   3199    1566.7683   740     1569.8401   766     1572.6998   807     1575.8066   3996    1578.7158   4000    1581.7253   3998    1587.6716   3997        
1524.8672   4000    1527.7986   344     1531.007    3134    1533.9382   3414    1537.0911   3754    1539.9902   3995    1546.1921   4000    1548.9072   946     1551.9818   1100    1555.0193   1281    1557.9146   1959    1561.2467   2852    1563.8364   3202    1566.7693   743     1569.8396   782     1572.6979   804     1575.8082   3995    1578.7159   3999    1581.7251   4000    1587.6716   3994        
1524.8666   3998    1527.7987   343     1531.0065   3143    1533.9382   3415    1537.0908   3749    1539.9897   3999    1546.1919   4000    1548.9053   943     1551.9819   1099    1555.0195   1282    1557.9146   1961    1561.2462   2861    1563.8362   3187    1566.7686   738     1569.8386   764     1572.699    802     1575.8079   4000    1578.7173   3994    1581.7249   3998    1587.6721   3997
```

> **IMAGES**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, so, I think in order to answer this you need to tell us a bit more about what exactly you're given and what exactly you want out. I think what you're saying is that you want to take in one of these plots and output which of the 3 channels it comes from. You say it's easy to recognize them by hand from looking at the graph but we only have 1 example from each so far. I would be inclined to say so far that its channel 1 if theres none with x values above 1550, channel 2 if there are x values above 1565 but none in the 1540-1560 range, and 3 otherwise.

Comment: I think your problem is probably more complicated than that but I'm not sure exactly how. Can you elaborate on what it is that characterizes the difference between channels?

Comment: Hi @AlexanderGruber. The input I have it is NOT the pictures but the stream of numbers you can find in the DATA paragraph. Only the numbers that represent the peaks you can see in the graphs. In addition this is just an example, the three channels may have the same number of sensors, but normally the mix of position (WL) and power can be enough to have them "appear" different. But I can I mathematical grab this difference in general?

Comment: The sum of powers that I am using now it is working for the settings (meaning the sensors installed for each channel) that I have now, but it is a bit weak and I was looking for something more general.

Comment: Yes, I figured the data was the input rather than the pictures. You say this is obvious from looking at the data (or a graph of it). Describe to me how you determine this when you're doing so. What mental reasoning are you using?

Comment: Yes, I was saying this is obvious from looking at the picture, not data. About the Human mind, I really wouldn't know, it seems to be doing everything by itself. I was say for example that if you remove some sensors from the picture of the first channel (example: the first and the 3rd) you can still easily understand that that picture is about channel one. But in this case we are talking about image recognition. For sure applying deep learning technics it will work, but I was looking for something simpler, a formula similar to the sum of power in terms of complexity

Comment: I might be able to help you with it, but can you give me a few more visual examples? I don't want to plot the data myself. Maybe if I see more examples, it will be more obvious to me what makes each channel distinctive.

Comment: The three graphs are related to just one example. Sensors (the spikes) may vary in number, position and power ... for any of the channels. 20 sensors max, the power limit is 4000, distance between sensors is about 3 nanometer. I will prepare some pictures to show other examples. The assumption is that usually they will never look the same. For example I will never be in the situation that three channel will have the same number of sensors, at the same WL and with the same power

Comment: bounty hunters, were are you all? :-(

Answer (score 1):

$1.$ On the recognizing step should be used normalized samples, such that
$$\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} \overline Y^2_j = 1,$$
where $N$ is the period.

$2.$ Patterns should be based on the average values of the significant quantity of samples and then normalized too.

$3.$ Samples and patterns should be synchronized. The simplest way is applying of some cyclically shifted patterns for each channel.

Good luck!